# DHT22 Temperature and Humidity Sensor Errors

Tags: python, linux, macos, raspberry-pi

I am using mac terminal and trying to use a raspberry pi 4 to capture and store values taken from a DHT22 sensor and I get these errors whenever I try to connect it in properly:
DHT sensor not found, check wiring
this is when I connect my DH22 sensor

```
De-initializing self.pulse_in
De-initializing self.pulse_in
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/humidity.py", line 26, in
temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 274, in temperature
self.measure()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 219, in measure
pulses = self._get_pulses_pulseio()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 141, in _get_pulses_pulseio
self.pulse_in.clear()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/bcm283x/pulseio/PulseIn.py", line 150, in clear
self._mq.send("c", True, type=1)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/humidity.py", line 44, in
dhtDevice.exit()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 93, in exit
self.pulse_in.deinit()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/bcm283x/pulseio/PulseIn.py", line 111, in deinit
procs.remove(self._process)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Can anyone make any sense of this?

My code is as follows:

```
    # SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 ladyada for Adafruit Industries
    SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
    import time
    import datetime
    import board
    import adafruit_dht
    Initial the dht device, with data pin connected to:
    
    dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4)
    
    e = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = "%s-%s-%s" % (e.day, e.month, e.year)
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H%M%S", t)
    file = open('humidityValues'+ date + '_' + current_time +'.txt', 'w')
    you can pass DHT22 use_pulseio=False if you wouldn't like to use pulseio.
    This may be necessary on a Linux single board computer like the Raspberry Pi,
    but it will not work in CircuitPython.
    dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D18)
    
    while True:
    try:
    # Print the values to the serial port
    temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
    temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
    humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
    t = time.local
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
    temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
    temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
    humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
    str = "time=" + current_time + " temp={0:0.1f}ºC humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature_c, humidity)
    print(str)
    file.write(str + "\n")
    
    except RuntimeError as error:
        # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
        print(error.args[0])
        time.sleep(2.0)
        continue
    except Exception as error:
        dhtDevice.exit()
        #raise error
    
    time.sleep(2.0)
```

I tried to remedy the problem with this:

```
    # SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 ladyada for Adafruit Industries
    SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
    import time
    import datetime
    import board
    import adafruit_dht
    Initial the dht device, with data pin connected to:
    
    dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4)
    
    e = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = "%s-%s-%s" % (e.day, e.month, e.year)
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H%M%S", t)
    file = open('humidityValues'+ date + '_' + current_time +'.txt', 'w')
    you can pass DHT22 use_pulseio=False if you wouldn't like to use pulseio.
    This may be necessary on a Linux single board computer like the Raspberry Pi,
    but it will not work in CircuitPython.
    dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D18, use_pulseio=False)
    
    while True:
    try:
    # Print the values to the serial port
    temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
    temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
    humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
    t = time.local
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
    temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
    temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
    humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
    str = "time=" + current_time + " temp={0:0.1f}ºC humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature_c, humidity)
    print(str)
    file.write(str + "\n")
    
    except RuntimeError as error:
        # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
        print(error.args[0])
        time.sleep(2.0)
        continue
    except Exception as error:
        dhtDevice.exit()
        #raise error
    
    time.sleep(2.0)
```

But, all I get are things like:
Checksum did not validate. Try again.
A full buffer was not returned. Try again.

Does anybody have any suggestions.

NOTICE: I am in no way passing the code above off as my own purely.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting - do you have the paragraphs starting `you can pass DHT22` in your code?

Comment: Being methodological is the key. First draw a schema of what you want to build (wiring). Then assemble accordingly and check your wiring. Then create a [mcve]. We are not in front of your workbench so without this kind of information and the guarantee you have checked it properly we are left to guess. Finally because those very essential steps are generally ignored at the very first stage of "development" broken sensors are legion. So if you check all boxes and get no result... Maybe your sensor is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I had several months ago a similar issue. Your script looks equal than the script i had found in a tutorial at first sight: https://pypi.org/project/adafruit-circuitpython-dht/

Following things could help:

- the Sensor **could be broken** (in the past 2 of 5 of my sensors didn't work)
- try connect the DHT22 on **5V** instead of **3,3V**
- i know that point is ugly but checking **wiring** is soooo important (i am sometimes blind :D )

just a hint when its working: try to calculate the *median* for precise data